# can't run rails db:migrate after upgrading to rails 5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Ruby 2.3.1.

I'm trying to upgrade my rails app from 4.2 to 5.0. So far I have:

- successfully upgraded my `Gemfile` and successfully run `bundle update rails`
- run `rails app:update` making sure not to overwrite any custom changes.
- added `ApplicationRecord` base class and have all of my models inherit from it.

Now I am trying to run `rails db:migrate` and am getting this error:

```
rails aborted!
TypeError: {:to_prepare=>"use ActiveSupport::Reloader.to_prepare instead", :to_cleanup=>"use ActiveSupport::Reloader.to_complete instead", :prepare!=>"use Rails.application.reloader.prepare! instead", :cleanup!=>"use Rails.application.reloader.reload! instead of cleanup + prepare"} is not a symbol nor a string
my_app/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is `enviornment.rb`:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize! # <--- the error happens here
```

FWIW, running `rails c` produces the same error.

What do I need to change to fix this? I'm not sure what other files would be useful to see. Let me know if I can share anything else.

### Update

I have added `ApplicationRecord` base class per  and have all of my models inherit from it. Source: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#active-record-models-now-inherit-from-applicationrecord-by-default

### Update 2

Running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` gets the same result as `rails db:migrate`

Comment: looks like deprecated thing

Comment: @Bohdan thanks for this reply. What action should I take to resolve this?

Comment: Refer to the rails guide on upgrading from 4 to 5 here:  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html  You'll notice that Models now inherit from ApplicationRecord instead of ActiveModel.  I'd start there.

Comment: @bkunzi01 thanks for the help! I've made all of my models inherit from `ApplicationRecord` but am still getting the same result. I have no Active Jobs and mailers are already inheriting from `ApplicationMailer < ActiveMailer::Base`

Comment: Did you try "bundle exec rake db:migrate" instead of rails db:migrate?  Also make sure you're using ruby 2.2.2 or greater.

Comment: This app is using ruby version 2.3.1. `bundle exec rake db:migrate` fails in the same way as `rails db:migrate`